# How to Detect Weigand Sensor Signal Pulses With stm32 Microcontroller Pin

Tags: stm32, sensors

I am trying to capture the voltage signal from a radially magnetized magnet measuring 6x2mm. The gap between the sensor and the magnet is approximately 1.0mm as shown in figure 01. I'm using a Weigand sensor for this purpose, and I intend to detect the signal with an STM32 microcontroller GPIO pin. The issue I'm facing is with the high voltage, which reaches approximately 60 volts peak-to-peak, as shown in Figure 02. Additionally, I've connected a Hall effect sensor to detect the signal in the same magnetic field, as depicted in Figure 03 (the yellow signal). Surprisingly, the number of detected pulses remains the same. I'm uncertain about how to safely interface this Weigand sensor signal with the microcontroller pin. Could you please provide guidance on this matter?

Figure_01 ---> https://www.arduinopak.com/Prd_Detail.aspx?Prd_ID=20022

Figure_02 --->  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tS7EN.jpg)

Figure_03 --->   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G79wn.jpg)

Furthermore, I have attempted to resolve this issue by following the transistor circuit specifications from the datasheet. The expected voltage is V02, as indicated in Figure 04. However, I am not achieving the accurate output signal. I used 2N2222A NPN and 3N2906 PNP transistors along with capacitors and resistors based on the datasheet values.

Figure_03(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPewI.png)

Comment: This question would be more suited to [Electronics StackExchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).